# There are a @Formula-like annotation to set calculated field from subquery in JPA (EclipseLink)?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

I am a very new JPA user.

I want to know how to set a field based on a calculated subquery value, something like:

```
@[Annotation]("select count(*) from ...") 
long calculatedField;
```

Is that posible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no JPA annotation what you said. But you can create your own annotation what you want and use your own annotation in your entity. See [this example](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/03/my-first-custom-annotation.html) to create and use custom annotation in JPA.

Answer (score 1):

I try do somthing like you with http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/MappingSelectionCriteria

I thing about put sql directly in mapping for column inside method
public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception;

When experiment fail (documentation is very poor), I checked this:

```
private BigDecimal quantityOrders;

@Column(name="(select 2 from dual) as quantityOrders",insertable = false, updatable = false)
public BigDecimal getQuantityOrders() {
    return quantityOrders;
}
```

... and, it is working !!!

Then I put more complicated select and it also working.
I can't find any documentation for that.

Comment: Interesting solution, but you won't be able to use the quantityOrders in JPQL where and having clauses. JPQL "select e from Entity e where e.quantityOrders=value" would generate SQL "select (select 2 from dual) as quantityOrders, ... where t1.(select 2 from dual) as quantityOrders = value"

Comment: Yes, you have right, but this is only substitute for hibernate annotation Formula. Moreover there will be problem when you want use alias (with CriteriaBuilder) for entity with that definied column. In annotation Formula is possible using word 'this' for pointing on current table. Maybe we can use metadata customizer, but still I don't known how.